# Make getDerivedStateFromProps behaves like componentDidMount when props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props, react-component

I have React parent-children components that communicates via props and the children is updated with a submit function.

Parent class:

```
   handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({
      items: Items // imported from dummy data
    })
  }

  // truncated (inside render function, state destructuring, etc)

    <Form submit={this.handleSubmit} />
      <Table 
      data={items}
      currentCards={currentCards}
      currentPage={currentPage}
      totalPages={totalPages}
      />
```

Children class:

```
// truncated (class Table, props constructor, set state from props)

   static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.data !== state.data) {
      return {
        data: props.data
        };
      }
      return null;
    }

// truncated (inside render function, state destructuring, etc)

    <Pagination
      totalRecords={totalCards}
      pageLimit={10}
      pageNeighbours={1}
      onPageChanged={onPageChanged}
    />

      <tbody>
        {currentCards.map((item, key) => (
          <tr key={key || "0"}>
// truncated
```

Pagination's `onPageChanged` is initiated on first load with `items` still empty, but not when  `handleSubmit` is pressed (which is triggering `getDerivedStateFromProps` to process items/data to populate `currentCards`).

I confirm Pagination's `onPageChanged` is not initiated upon `getDerivedStateFromProps` because I set a breakpoint inside `Pagination` and `data` inside children's `render` already got updated upon submit (but not `currentCards` since it needs `onPageChanged` to be initiated first)

ah, and my `Pagination` code is also based from [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/l29rokm9rm)

In short, how to re-compute pagination when data is retrieved with `handleSubmit`?

**Update:**

Here's a [CodeSandbox of what I'm trying to do](https://codesandbox.io/s/81j11vqwpj), if you click submit, `Pagination` is not re-mounted

Comment: In your loading are you updating the array that contains the data or creating a new one?

If its the former (updating) then the equality check will come back true and your code will not be run.

Generally its best to have immutable objects/lists and create new ones when adding/removing data.

Comment: Props are copied to children state, including data and confirmed on `submit` with new data loaded, but the `currentCards` resulted from `onPageUpdate` is only called on initial mount when data state is set to `[]`